# how to convert dictionary of array to list and as key value in python

Tags: python

i have a dictionary with key value but values are in array,
i want to convert the array into value for each keys

```
#this is my dictionay
input_dic = {
    'pm_25': [22.5, 23.8, 24.9], 
    'pm_10': [2.76, 6.76, 2.76], 
    'humidity': [55, 10, 85], 
    'temprature': [12.7, 41.1, 85.1]
    }
# i want like this 
    want_to = [
        {'pm_25': 22.5, 'pm_10': 2.76, 'humidity': 55, 'temprature': 12.7},
        {'pm_25': 23.8, 'pm_10': 6.76, 'humidity': 10, 'temprature': 41.1},
        {'pm_25': 24.9, 'pm_10': 2.76, 'humidity': 85, 'temprature': 85.1},
    ]
```

please any one know how to convert this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[dict(zip(input_dic, values))
 for values in zip(*input_dic.values())]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. nice approach

Answer (score 3):

You can use list and dictionary comprehension as in the following one liner:

```
[{k: v[i] for k, v in input_dic.items()} for i in range(len(input_dic["pm_25"]))]
```

Or if you want your code to be more readable and pythonic:

```
n = len(input_dic["pm_25"])
new_list = [{} for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for k, v in input_dic.items():
        new_list[i][k] = v[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

[@zaibaq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10071237/zaibaq) has already posted a very concise solution. This is a bit elaborative one. This might become a lengthy approach if the number of keys is large.

```
input_dic = {
    'pm_25': [22.5, 23.8, 24.9], 
    'pm_10': [2.76, 6.76, 2.76], 
    'humidity': [55, 10, 85], 
    'temprature': [12.7, 41.1, 85.1]
}

num_entries = len(input_dic['pm_25'])

result = []

#Create new dictionaries and append them in the results array.
for i in range(num_entries):
    new_dict = {
        'pm_25': input_dic['pm_25'][i],
        'pm_10': input_dic['pm_10'][i],
        'humidity': input_dic['humidity'][i],
        'temprature': input_dic['temprature'][i],
    }
    
    result.append(new_dict)

print(result)
```